# How do I get RubyMine to look for step definitions in a different language?

Tags: cucumber, rubymine

Cucumber offers different languages out of the box. https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Spoken-languages

RubyMine, however, seems to ignore the step definitions starting with something else than english (e.g. Gegeben (german) instead of Given).

How do I get RubyMine to find my step definitions?

Comment: This seems to be a known issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-16697